# INSTALL_FAILED_DUPLICATE_PERMISSION: Package com.google.ar.core attempting to redeclare permission

Tags: applications, adb, google-play-store, installation, uninstallation

After the deletion of Google Play Services for AR I can't install it anymore.

Google Play Store shows an error when I'm trying to install:

> Can't install Google Play Services for AR

I have checked logcat and saw an error

```
10-31 21:07:18.787  4837  4837 E Finsky  : [2] rir.e(27): Submitter: commit error message INSTALL_FAILED_DUPLICATE_PERMISSION: Package com.google.ar.core attempting to redeclare permission com.google.ar.core.DYNAMIC_RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED_PERMISSION already owned by com.google.ar.core
10-31 21:07:18.793  4837 26991 E Finsky  : [1336] qyj.a(63): IV2: Task Failed: tid:1000000028, statusCode:6004
10-31 21:07:18.793  4837 26991 E Finsky  : com.google.android.finsky.installercommon.InstallerException: Status: 6004
10-31 21:07:18.793  4837 26991 E Finsky  :      at riq.apply(PG:131)
10-31 21:07:18.793  4837 26991 E Finsky  :      at apyf.e(PG:3)
10-31 21:07:18.793  4837 26991 E Finsky  :      at apyg.run(PG:42)
10-31 21:07:18.793  4837 26991 E Finsky  :      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
10-31 21:07:18.793  4837 26991 E Finsky  :      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:644)
10-31 21:07:18.793  4837 26991 E Finsky  :      at nvr.run(PG:147)
10-31 21:07:18.793  4837 26991 E Finsky  :      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
```

But `com.google.ar.core` package is not installed.

`adb pm list permissions -f` shows that the permission is still exists.

```
+ permission:com.google.ar.core.DYNAMIC_RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED_PERMISSION
  package:com.google.ar.core
  protectionLevel:signature
```

Installation with adb gives the save error

```
adb: failed to install arcore.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_DUPLICATE_PERMISSION: Package com.google.ar.core attempting to redeclare permission com.google.ar.core.DYNAMIC_RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED_PERMISSION already owned by com.google.ar.core]
```

Device info:

- Google Pixel 6a
- Android 14 Beta (U1B2.230922.010)

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. Looks like Google Play Services for AR is a system app on Pixel devices. How did you uninstall it? Is the device rooted?